# Drupal Views - Custom Theme for a field

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view, drupal-theming, drupal-fields

Two quick questions regarding custom theming of view fields in Drupal 6 -

(a) I know that we can include a custom theme for a view field in a appropriately named template file but I notice that it has to be placed in the theme folder.

However, I want this theme file to be bundled with my module and was wondering if it could be done somehow?

(b) Can we have a preprocess function to set custom variables before the field is themed?

Comment: (a) did you tried to put template file in your module directory?

Comment: I did try. Added it there and to the module_theme hook. Didn't seem to work (ie) from the Views UI, when I go to Theme Information and click Rescan Template Files, the template file doesn't get picked up.

It only does when it is in the theme folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) I suspect it will be difficult because of the limitations of [preprocess functions](http://drupal.org/node/258089). Depending on what you need to do, you might be able to use the hook_views_pre_render function.

(b) Here are some tips on [theming views with preprocess functions](http://evolvingweb.ca/story/theming-views-drupal-templates-and-preprocess-functions).